# Storing and Retrieving Information from app.config/xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net, config, app-config

I have a requirement for storing configuration information relating to a number of different database interfaces.  The application will be developed as a Windows Service and I wish to store and  retrieve key configuration information from either a custom xml file or the app.config file.  The information to be stored/retrieved conforms roughly to the following:

```
Interface1:
    Source:
        Table: source_table
            Cols:
                column1: source_col1
                column2: source_col2
                column3: source_col3
                column4: source_col4
                column5: source_col5
                column6: source_col6
                etc..
    Dest:
        Table: dest_table
            Cols:
                column1: dest_col1 
                column2: dest_col2
                column3: dest_col3
                column4: dest_col4
                column5: dest_col5
                column6: dest_cols6 
                etc...

Interface2:
    Source:
        Table: source_table
            Cols:
                column1: source_col1
                column2: source_col2
                column3: source_col3
                column4: source_col4
                column5: source_col5
                column6: source_col6
                etc..
    Dest:
        Table: dest_table
            Cols:
                column1: dest_col1 
                column2: dest_col2
                column3: dest_col3
                column4: dest_col4
                column5: dest_col5
                column6: dest_col6  
                etc...
```

My experience with app.config is limited to storing simple key/value pairs, so I am looking for some inspiration as to how best to proceed.

Kind Regards

Paul J.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a custom XML file or a Custom Configuration Section in your app.config in which you will have to create a public class that inherits from the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) class. I would go with the custom config section as its more "out of the box".

Basic example:
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx/